# Solving equation $\log_y(\log_y(x))= \log_n(x)$ for $n$

Tags: logarithms

I'm just wondering, if I log a constant twice with the same base $y$,

$$\log_y(\log_y(x))= \log_n(x)$$

Can it be equivalent to logging the same constant with base $n$? If yes, what is variable $n$ equivalent to?

Comment: In light of your comment to Avatar, you might be interested in my post [Exponential and Logarithmic Commutativity](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4023927).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Your post is pretty inspirational. Thanks for sharing! I've learnt a new approach to solving log problems from it. When I have time I would definitely look into question 5 and 6 and try to find a solution for them. They look fun.

Comment: If you send me an email (I can't find your email address), I can send you a .pdf file of my original submitted "article". The .pdf version I have is a little more complete than the published version (because of space considerations), which in turn is longer than what I posted. Click on my name to find my email address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\log_y(\log_y(x))= \log_n(x)$$ $$\implies \log_y(\log_y(x))= \frac{\log_e(x)}{\log_e(n)}$$ $$\implies \log_e(n)=\frac{\log_e(x)}{\log_y(\log_y(x))}$$ $$\implies n=e^{\frac{\log_e(x)}{\log_y(\log_y(x))}}$$

Thus, for given $x,y$, if $e^{\frac{\log_e(x)}{\log_y(\log_y(x))}}$ is defined, then that is the value for $n$.

Comment: Bravo! I have once again witnessed the beauty of mathematics.

Answer (score 7):

No - take as example, $x = 1$. Then $\log_y(x) = 0$ and $\log_y(\log_y(x))$ is undefined. However as $x = 1$, $\log_n(x)$ is always equal to $0$, which means that $\log_y(\log_y(x)) \neq \log_n(x)$

Comment: $x=y$ is a similarly nice example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that with the initial conditions for a logarithm satisfying.

The conditions for log(x) to the base n  are: x > 0, n > 0 and n != 1.

so you should be careful with the domain that you are choosing.

Comment: i think  my example is  one  reason of this

Comment: Yes, but you have to stick to the domain of the function as well.

Answer (score 1):

suppose $x=4$   and  $y=2$  then $\log_y(x)=2$
and   $\log_2(2)=1$

which means that $\log_n(4)=1$  it means that  $n=4$. I don't know if it is  helpful for you.